# Call Migrations in Laravel 5.4 Controller

Tags: laravel-5

I'm creating a SAAS application with multi tenant databases. So, whenever a person registers on the site. I'm creating a database on run time and then after a connection on the fly. I want to run the migrations to create tables in the new database.

Everything is working fine but the migrations are not happening. 
Here is my code which calls my migration:

```
  Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => 'database/migrations', '--force' => true));
```

I'm already creating the migrations tables before calling this command.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 Artisan::call('migrate',
        [
            '--database' => 'tenant',
            '--path'     => 'database/migrations',
            '--step'     => true,
            '--force'    => true
        ]);
```

Replace `tenant` with your database connection name.